# translate string in asyncValidate function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin, admin-on-rest

How I can translate ***error string*** using:

```
import { translate } from 'react-admin';

const CompanyValidate = (values) => {
    return asyncValidate('companies', [
        {
            filters: {
                'code': code,
            },
            errorMessage: {
                'code': 'Error String'
            }
        }
    ]);
};

const CompanyCreate = (props) => (
    <Create
        {...props}
    >
        <SimpleForm
        asyncValidate={CompanyAsyncValidate}>
            <TextInput
                label="Code"
                source="code"
                validate={required()}/>
        <SimpleForm/>
    <Create/>
  );
```

translate("Text") not working in asyncValidate for me.

UPD: I have added more code.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @Oleg  I have added more code.

Comment: Where is 'translate' call function?

Comment: @Oleg Problem is: dunno how to use it at this case(meaning in asyncValidate function).

Comment: asyncValidate functiion in CompanyValidate  return promise?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2208

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `translate()` function  into your `CompanyAsyncValidate` function.
As in documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#validation, this function will be passed with `props.translate` into your validation function.

However despite of documentation it is not on the 3rd position as argument but on the 2nd.

Comment: And it will be just: 'code': this.props.translate("loco.error.error_string")?

Comment: you can use then your function argument like that: `props.translate("loco.error.error_string")`